# heroku app crashing - dependencies.rb:304:in `depend_on': No such file to load -- errors_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crash, heroku

I'm deploying my Rails app to Heroku (which works just fine on my Mac), when deployed to Heroku the app crashes and here is the log trace..

There seems to be some problem with my Gems. Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

```
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `depend_on': No such file to load -- errors_helper (LoadError)
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-05T03:38:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-07-05T03:38:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```